# Comma before and after an email address of webmail.send

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, smtp, ssms

I am  trying to implement smtp on asp.net web pages (razor page) and sql server 2017. The email notification was supposed to send after submitting a form using an email address stored in sql database but each I click submit, the notification fails to send.
So, I tried debugging it by adding a breakpoint and stepped into the smtp initiallizer. I found out that there is a comma (,) before and after the email address. When I remove the two commas, the notification sends but I don't know how to permanently remove it without having to do it by putting a breakpoint so that my application can run.

Attached is the screenshoot.

Thank you so much for your help.

```
// Initialize WebMail helper
 WebMail.SmtpServer = "smtp.office365.com";
 WebMail.SmtpPort = 25;
 WebMail.UserName = "help@me.please";
 WebMail.Password = "Help123";
 WebMail.From = "help@me.please";
 WebMail.EnableSsl = true;



 WebMail.Send(to: Email,
 subject: "Visitor Alert",
 body: " Hello: <br/> " + "Hope you're having a good time!);
```

[image]

Comment: Are the commas in the database? Did you try `email.Replace(',','')`?

Comment: No, there is no comma in the database. I can only see that when I set a break point

Comment: No problem hope it helped

Comment: If you could, please up-vote and mark my answer as correct if it worked for you

Answer (score 1):

It seems there are invalid entries in your database, you should validate that because everybody might be trying to put in corrupted data. Another possibility is that some parsing went wrong which resulted in corrupted data.

Anyhow, to fix this specific case, you can trim the email address:

```
WebMail.Send(to: email.Trim(','),
             subject: "Visitor Alert",
             body: " Hello: <br/> " + "Hope you're having a good time!);
```

Nevertheless, this is just fixing a symptom for another underlying problem.

Comment: @Chidi: hi, thanks is expressed by upvoting and/or marking as answer (the big "V") ;-)

Comment: I did that immediately the error was resolved but received a pop up that I don't have up to 15 reputations for it to be added, though it will be recorded. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

What would work is the following:

```
// Initialize WebMail helper
WebMail.SmtpServer = "smtp.office365.com";
WebMail.SmtpPort = 25;
WebMail.UserName = "help@me.please";
WebMail.Password = "Help123";
WebMail.From = "help@me.please";
WebMail.EnableSsl = true;



WebMail.Send(to: Email.Replace(',',''),
subject: "Visitor Alert",
body: " Hello: <br/> " + "Hope you're having a good time!)";
```

I added a

```
.Replace(',','')
```

which removes the unwanted commas from any email you have

Comment: If OP doesn't, I will. Can't mark it as answer though ;-)